# React apollo query string for array of objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, apollo, react-apollo

I will have my api return data in this format

```
[{ 
“Type”:”alpha”,
“Count”:5

},
{
“Type”:”beta”,
“Count”:7
}

]
```

What would be my query string?

```
const Levels = gql`
  {
Levelsquery {
  Type
  Count
}
  }
`;
```

Above does not work because there is no levelsquery key, the whole response is an array

The current problem is that this api is kind of fixed from the server,it does not matter if it is a graphql query or a simple REst query, the output will always be the same so then I need to handle my client query to reflect it’s output

I know it is wrong to have this in graphql, but this is what it is and I cannot change it currently

Comment: you need to provide more information
I don't see the schema from your server, a full query from the client. Somehow react doesn't get - what does it mean, error, null? Show more information because you won't get an answer to this

Comment: @YevheniiHerasymchuk  given more details, hope it helps